"это был" or "это было"?
In this poem by Boris Pasternak we have this verse:

Однако это был подлог,

Why is it correct? If это is the subject, shouldn't we have "это было подлог" (except that from a metric viewpoint it would not be satisfying)?

This is definitely correct Russian and not just "poetic licence". This is standard Russian. Это был настоящий мужчина. Это была моя самая заветная мечта.
It's clear that это is not actually parsed as the subject of был. I suppose if you analyse to a degree that it is not worth a student of a language doing, then настоящий мужчина would be the subject of the copula, and это the predicate or complement, or a word that stands for the predicate or complement.
(Most linguistic sources do say that это is the subject of such sentences, but there is clearly a difficulty with the subject not making the verb neuter and so you could debate the parsing of the sentence. You could also just see это as an invariable pointing word, a bit like вот or voici.)
Also note that you can have the neuter verb if the noun is in the instrumental: это было подлогом.

"Это" here serves a similar function to "it" in "It is raining" in English. Its use in Russian is slightly more common and versatile than the English counterpart, but the essence is the same.

In English "it" is the subject of the sentence "It is raining" and the subject "it" matches the verb "is", while the previous answer stated that это is not the subject of Однако это был подлог.

Well, the verb is not conjugated as if это were the subject, but the way of parsing such sentences is a matter of debate. Copula sentences have a subject and predicate, but as the copula signifies identity, it can be a matter of interpretation which is the subject and which the predicate.
